# How do I fix "Could not autowire. No beans of 'MyRepository' type found"?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, repository, javabeans, autowired

I have this hierarchy in my project:

```
▼ server
  ▼ myproject
    ▼ src
      ▼ main
        ▼ java
          ▼ rest
            ▼ repository
              Ⓘ MyRepository
        ▶ resources
      ▼ test
        ▼ java
          ▼ rest
            Ⓒ MyRepositoryTest
```

This is the **MyRepository** interface:

```
public interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<String, Integer> {
}
```

This is the **MyRepositoryTest** test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class MyRepositoryTest {
    ...
    @Autowired MyRepository myRepository;
    ...
}
```

The error occurs on the autowired myRepository instance in the test class. It says `Could not autowire. No beans of 'MyRepository' type found`. I've searched a bit and tried to add `@Component`, `@Repository` and so on, but nothing really helps. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure that's true, I've done it before. I've just restructured this project. Before I did that it worked, even though I Autowired that exact same Repository.

Comment: Is it also failing when you run it? Or is it your IDE (IntelliJ?) that shows the error on mouse hover?

Comment: @MevlütÖzdemir it also fails when I run it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this, set your package in `@ComponentScan` of the class `AppConfig`:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class AdminEvaluatorTest {
    @Autowired MyRepository myRepository;

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("com.<your-package>")
    public static class AppConfig {
    }
}
```

Comment: The error I had is gone, however when I run the test now it gives that says `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`

Comment: Is it working right now ? @Ben

Comment: No it's not working. The @ContectConfiguration just moved the problem somewhere else, now I just have another issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71124665/why-do-i-keep-getting-the-failed-to-load-applicationcontext-exception?noredirect=1#comment125727713_71124665

Answer (score 2):

you can try to specify the base packages that should be included in the component scan. For example:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example.demo", "com.example.model"})
```

the annotation is indicating that the component scan should include the com.example.demo and com.example.model packages. This means that Spring will search for and register any Spring-managed components (such as `@Controller, @Service, and @Repository` beans) in those packages, and make them available for dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have @EnableAutoConfiguration under your @SpringBootApplication at the main class? Try to set it.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
....
public class MyProject{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyProject.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: redundant annotation

Answer (score 0):

Looks like framework is not scanning package which have test class in your application

From hierarchy shared above, package for **MyRepository** interface is "rest.repository" and package for **MyRepositoryTest** class is "rest".

Try changing package of **MyRepositoryTest** class as well to "rest.repository". This should solve the problem.